# Sinalizar respostas Antigas, sim ou não?

Tags: debate, sinalização

As vezes o Bot do StackOverflow sobe com algumas perguntas antiga, ou algum usuário edita ou responde uma pergunta antiga e nela vemos outras respostas com baixa qualidade, sem votos ou réplicas negativas etc.

Hoje em dia vale a pena sinalizar essas respostas antigas respondidas por links por exemplo ou que seriam consideradas como de baixa qualidade, ou que seriam melhor adequadas como comentários a pergunta. Ou nesse caso é melhor deixar como está já que tem anos que a resposta está lá parada e não foi sinalizada?

***Devemos aplicar o "padrão atual" de tolerância para as "respostas antigas" e sem votos?***

Comment: Se julgar que esta está ruim porque nao? O fluxo de perguntas em determinados horarios do dia, bem como posts em finais de semana e feriados pode ser altos ou passam despercebidos por muita gente, e acaba perdurando no site. Se ver um caso desses, sinta-se a vontade pra sinalizar :)

Comment: Sinalize hoje, sinalize amanhã, sinalize sempre

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sinalização só deve ser usado em **alguns casos**:

- **spam:**

  Faz propaganda, sem explicar a ligação com o assunto e o autor não declara sua relação com o produto ou serviço citado.
- **rude ou abusivo:**

  Uma pessoa sensata acharia este conteúdo inapropriado para uma discussão respeitosa.
- **não é uma resposta:**

  Esta resposta não é uma tentativa concreta de resolver o problema. Seria melhor transformada em comentário, edição, outra pergunta ou excluída.
- **qualidade muito baixa:**

  Esta resposta tem graves problemas de formatação ou conteúdo. É improvável que esta resposta seja recuperável por meio de edição e talvez seja necessário removê-la.
- **precisa de atenção dos moderadores:**

  Há um outro problema que precisa de intervenção dos moderadores.

> Note que uma resposta de **qualidade muito baixa**, como descrito são as irrecuperáveis.

Você pode sinalizar sempre, eu mesmo sinalizei 2 spams bem antigos, que ninguém tinha se dado conta.

Agora se a resposta é apenas ruim (você considera ruim), então uso o downvote é mais que suficiente, independente se for antiga ou nova, os votos são para **avaliar a qualidade da postagem** (é claro que tem uma turminha que usa por picuinha ou porque não entende de um assunto e ainda sim quer se intrometer e vota sem ter competência no assunto)